# Elliptic curve ed25519 vs ed448 - Differences

Tags: ed25519, ed448

Other than key size, What are some differences between the Elliptic curve ed25519 and ed448?

Comment: Parameter choices. Intended security level. If you need more detail, just look at the specifications for them both.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Edwards25519** is the twisted Edwards curve $$-x^2 + y^2 = 1 - (121665/121666) x^2 y^2$$ over the prime field $\mathbb F_p$ where $p = 2^{255} - 19$.  The coefficient $d = -121665/121666$ was chosen to so that this curve is birationally equivalent to the Montgomery curve $y^2 = x^3 + 486662 x^2 + x$, called Curve25519, whose coefficient 486662 was chosen to be the smallest integer in absolute value satisfying the security criteria[[1]](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#curve25519).  The group of $\mathbb F_p$-rational points has composite order $8 p_1$ for a 253-bit prime $p_1$, and its twist has composite order $4 p_2$ for a 253-bit prime $p_2$.  **Edwards25519 is designed to make the cost of a discrete log computation cost at least about $2^{128}$ bit operations to break the first of any number of targets.**

**Edwards448**, also known as [Ed448-Goldilocks](http://ed448goldilocks.sourceforge.net), is the untwisted Edwards curve $$x^2 + y^2 = 1 - 39081 x^2 y^2$$ over the prime field $\mathbb F_p$ where $p = 2^{448} - 2^{224} - 1$.  The coefficient $d = -39081$ was chosen to be the smallest integer in absolute value satisfying the same security criteria as edwards25519, together with the additional constraint that the order of the group of $\mathbb F_p$-rational points have order below $p$, namely $4 p_1$ for a 446-bit prime $p_1$.  There is also a birationally equivalent Montgomery curve $y^2 = x^3 + 156326 x^2 + x$ derived from edwards448, called Curve448.  **Edwards448 is designed to make the cost of a discrete log computation cost about $2^{224}$ bit operations to break the first of any number of targets.**  Of course, since $2^{128}$ bit operations is already infeasible, **edwards448 is really a hedge against modest cryptanalytic advances.**

Ed25519 is specifically an instance of the EdDSA signature scheme[[2]](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#ed25519)[[3]](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#eddsa) with edwards25519 as the curve, SHA-512 as the hash function, an optional context identifier for compatibility, *etc.*; likewise Ed448 is an instance of EdDSA with edwards448 as the curve, SHAKE256 as the hash function, an obligatory domain identifier, *etc.*  See [RFC 8032](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032) for the details of EdDSA instantiation, and [RFC 7748](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7748) for the curve definitions.

The only major substantive differences are in security level and performance:

- **Security level:** Edwards25519 aims for a ‘128-bit security level’, and edwards448 aims for a ‘224-bit “Spinal Tap-grade” security level’—not actually a meaningful difference in the real world unless there is a modest cryptanalytic advance in computing elliptic curve discrete logs.
- **Key size:** Edwards448 points and scalars are 1.75x the size of edwards25519 points and scalars.
- **Fixed-base scalar multiplication:** Edwards448 costs about 1.5x what edwards25519 costs.
- **Variable-base scalar multiplication:** Edwards448 costs about 5x what edwards25519 costs.

  - (See SUPERCOP [dh](https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-dh.html) and [sign](https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-sign.html) for details.)

Edwards25519 has $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ while edwards448 has $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, so there are some differences in protocols beyond DH and signing, but not really substantive: for encoding points indistinguishably from uniform random strings, edwards25519 supports only Elligator 2, while edwards448 supports Elligator 1 and Elligator 2[[4]](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#elligator), but I don't know of any advantages to Elligator 1; both support a prime-order group encoding that avoids pitfalls with cofactors[[5]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-47989-6_34), with a couple of different software implementations, [Ristretto](https://ristretto.group) for Edwards25519  and [libdecaf](https://sourceforge.net/p/ed448goldilocks/code/ci/master/tree/) for Edwards448.  Both curves are designed for traditional discrete log applications and pass the [SafeCurves criteria](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/); neither curve is pairing-friendly.

**In brief, the two curves were designed with essentially the same *qualitative* security criteria and differ only on *quantitative* security level and performance.**

Answer (score 10):

- The Ed25519 prime has $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, while Ed448 has $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. This influences the square root algorithm.
- The $a$ elliptic curve parameter is $-1$ in Ed25519, and $1$ in Ed448. This influences the elliptic curve formulas.
- Ed25519 uses SHA-512 as the internal hash function, while Ed448 uses SHAKE256 from the SHA-3 family (the same applies for the prehashed version, if used). The input to the internal hash function is handled differently in Ed25519: if not using the prehashed version, then it's the message itself; otherwise, the message (actually the hash) is prefixed with a domain separation string. In Ed448 the prefix is always there.
- The Ed25519 cofactor is $8$, while the Ed448 is cofactor is $4$. This influences the scalar "clamping" mechanism that makes sure that the order of public keys is a multiple of the cofactor.