# What is "spinal-tap grade" security?

Tags: ed25519, ed448

As stated [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67457/elliptic-curve-ed25519-vs-ed448-differences/67468#67468) Ed448 is different from Ed25519 because of "spinal-tap grade" security. What does this mean?

Comment: I would not agree with that assessment of the security level, for me, "spinal-tap grade" would be at least 576-bits of security, which would be an 1152-bit elliptic curve

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is security on a 0-10 scale that goes to 11.

The cost of cryptanalysis to break a cryptosystem with a 128-bit security level, like Ed25519, is out of reach for humanity already.  A higher security level like Ed448's doesn't have any actual meaning with current understanding of cryptanalytic attacks.  The only purpose it serves is to hedge against *potential modest future advances* in cryptanalysis—a radical advance like a cheap quantum computer would devastate Ed25519 and Ed448 alike, of course.

<sub>P.S.  I see you tagged this [jwt](/questions/tagged/jwt) and [jwe](/questions/tagged/jwe).  JWT and JWE, and JOSE generally, provide a different sense of ‘spinal-tap grade’ security, which is that they are a parody of security.</sub>

Comment: Here is the [relevant clip for the curious](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMSV4OteqBE)