# Which elliptic curve was used by Thunderbird OpenPGP and which bitlength?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pgp

If one looks at `Account Settings > End-to-End-Encryption > Add Key` and creates a new key then gets the option EC. But you can't choose the bit length nor does one know which curve is used.

Anyone who knows that? Anyone who knows how secure that is?

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6637

Comment: @kelalaka thanks, but I already knew that document ... the problem is: I generated it with Thunderbird (which uses OpenPGP). While there is a variety of EC for OpenPGP, there is only the choice "EC" in Thunderbird. They do not mention bitlength or which curve they use. Which is weird, since OpenPGP provides different curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've downloaded the [source code](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/archive/tip.zip) from [the developer site](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file). All the encrypted related parts under the [libgcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libgcrypt)

> Libgcrypt is a cryptography library developed as a separated module of GnuPG. It can also be used independently of GnuPG, but depends on its error-reporting library Libgpg-error.

And those are listed as the supported curve in the library

- NIST (P-256, P-384, P-521)
- SECG (secp256k1)
- ECC Brainpool / RFC 5639 (P256r1, P384r1, P512r1)
- Bernstein Curve25519
- Curve448
- GOST R 34.10-2012 (RFC 7091)
- SM2

Which one is used? Search files excluding the `libgcrypt` directory since it is the exact copy of it.

A `grep`
`grep -r  curve tools/ build/ calendar/ chat/ mail mailnews/ python/ suite/ taskcluster/ tools/`

in the command line displays only

`curve25519`

This curve is used for public-key signature system as [Ed2559](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/).

Curve25519 is also known as the Bernstein curve. It is one of the most secure curves for the listed criteria as in the [safecurves.cr.yp.to/](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/).

If you want to read more about how secure the curve is, see our canonical answer;

- [Summarize the mathematical problem at the heart of breaking a Curve25519 public key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/50405/18298)

And note that if ever Shor's period finding algorithm is built with enough qbits the curve will be no more secure.

- 2008, [Shor’s discrete logarithm quantum algorithm for
  elliptic curves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0301141), Proos and Zalks.

Also;

> [Edwards25519 aims for a ‘128-bit security level](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67468/18298)

Comment: Thank you very much!